# How to use array of different struct type for the same job in c

Tags: c

I have to pass array of different struct type to a function which has to perform same functionality.

```
void chklink_state(void *links, int count)
{
    int i;
    int ret;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
       if (links[i].curr_status != links[i].prev_status)
         links[i].prev_status = links[i].curr_status;
    }
 }

main()
{ 
   struct gre_info gre_infos[10];
   struct vti_info vti_infos[10];
   //populate data with some functions
   chklink_state(gre_infos, 10);
   chklink_state(vti_infos, 10);
}
```

But getting error compiling with gcc. If I use union I have to use switch case for different structure type. If I use casting I have to cast `links` to different struct type variables then have to use switch case.

Is it possible to do mentioned operation without using switch case or if else?

Comment: You can use a `struct` which contains a `union` as well as the members that are common to them all. The function would deal with the parts that are common (non-union) members.

Comment: Please show us your attempt to use a union. -- How should such a function correctly step through the arrays of different structures, if it needs to be aware of potentially different structure sizes, without knowing the exact structure definitions?

Comment: "If I use union I have to use switch case for different structure type. " --> "use switch case" is only one of many approaches.  Post your `union` attempt and definitions of `struct gre_info`, `struct vti`.

Comment: With `void chklink_state(void *links, int count)` and its `void *links`, you simply can't solve the problem - you **must** have information to know what the `void *` actually points to.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use unions, you could define the functionality in a macro.
Macros do not have types (they are essentially just text replacement), but be careful using them because they have a number of [pitfalls](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Pitfalls.html#Macro-Pitfalls).

Without knowing more about the internal structure of the structs `gre_info` and `vti_info`, here is how I would define a macro to achieve your desired goal:

```c
#define CHKLINK_STATE(LINKS, COUNT) \
    do { \
         int i; \
         int ret; \
         for (i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) \
         { \
             if (LINKS[i].curr_status != LINKS[i].prev_status) \
                 LINKS[i].prev_status = LINKS[i].curr_status; \
         } \
    } while (0)
```

Notice that I wrapped the entire function definition in a do-while loop.
This is to avoid one of the pitfalls I mentioned - [swallowing the semicolon](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Swallowing-the-Semicolon.html#Swallowing-the-Semicolon).

Now back in main, you would call the macro just as you would a function:

```c
main()
    { 
       struct gre_info gre_infos[10];
       struct vti_info vti_infos[10];
       //populate data with some functions
       CHKLINK_STATE(gre_infos, 10);
       CHKLINK_STATE(vti_infos, 10);
    }
```

Comment: Side note: If you are using C11, then you can use the [`_Generic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/generic-selection?view=msvc-170) keyword to define generic functions

Comment: `_Generic` is fun, but it does not allow definition of type-generic functions.  It's most common use is in defining type-generic *macros*.  In particular, it does not especially serve the OP's objective to write a single function that handles data of multiple types. However, having two or more *type-specific* functions, `_Generic` could provide for a macro that produces calls to the appropriate one based on the type of one of the arguments.